# Managing UIImageViews in an xib in Xcode 5

Tags: uiimageview, xib

I have two UIImageViews in an xib file for my app. Is there any way to, non programmatically or programmatically put one behind the other. I need the one placed after the first one to be under the first one. Are there any selection areas I've missed in the UI of Xcode 5?

Answer (score 1):

Just put both `UIImageview` on same rect. If by dragging you are not able to handle this. Then select xib file then `UIimageView` and from left view of xcode, on top select "**Size Inspector**". Place **both** **UIImageView on same (x,y,w.h).**

you can do this by **programatically too by setting frame of both UIImageView on same rect.**

Also you can **reduce alpha property of UIimageview** which is on top. So that **bottom UIImageview also visible**.